# In Java how should I command a 2D point to move along the vector line of distance to another point?

Tags: java, position, distance, move, point

I have a simple class 2Dpoints with two fields, x and y. I want to write a code so that I could command one point to moves slowly to another point, like so that it moves on the vector line of their distances. But I don't know how?
I've first thought  that it should contain a for loop so that it would know, it should move till it reaches the other point
something like for(int d=0 ; d<distance ; d++) but I don't know how should I then command it so that it would move on the line?

```
import java.lang.Math.*;

public class Punkt { 

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Punkt(int x, int y) {
        this.x=x;
        this.y=y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setX(int distance) {
        x = x + distance;
    }

    public void setY(int distance) {
        y = y + distance;
    }

    public void moveAbout(int dx, int dy) {
        x = x + dx;
        y = y + dy;
    }

    /// method for calculating the distance to another point
    public double giveDistance(Punkt otherPoint) {
        return Math.sqrt(
            (otherPoint.getY() - y) * 
            (otherPoint.getY() - y) + 
            (otherPoint.getX() - x) * 
            (otherPoint.getX() - x));
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Please do not use the plural forms for class names. `Point` instead of `Points`. it is a kind of cross-lang convention

Comment: thank you @AlexanderAlexandrov for the advice, I've changed it.

Comment: Wait a little im gonna prepare full example on repl)

Comment: I think that you're using the "vector" tag improperly. The tag is for a single-dimensional array rather than a mathematical vector.

Comment: @NomadMaker Oh, I didn't know, have changed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've commented the major lines:

```java
import static java.lang.Math.*;

/**
 * Immutable structure. Functional way
 */
class Point { 
  public final double x;
  public final double y;

  public Point(double x, double y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  /**
   * Here you are. This is what you want to implement.
   * from.moveTo(0.0, to) => from
   * from.moveTo(1.0, to) => to
   *
   * @param by - from 0.0 to 1.0 (from 0% to 100%)
   * @param target - move toward target by delta
   */
  public Point moveTo(double by, Point target) {
    Point delta = target.sub(this);
    return add(delta.dot(by));
  }

  public Point add(Point point) {
    return new Point(x + point.x, y + point.y);
  }

  public Point sub(Point point) {
    return new Point(x - point.x, y - point.y);
  }

  public Point dot(double v) {
    return new Point(v * x, v * y);
  }

  public double dist(Point point) {
    return sub(point).len();
  }

  public double len() {
    return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
  }

  public String toString() {
    return x + ":" + y;
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Point source = new Point(2, 3);
    Point target = new Point(-4, 9);
    // You can utilize the cycle or implement kind of timer to animate something
    for (int t = 0; t <= 100; t++) {
      System.out.println(source.moveTo(0.01 * t, target));
    }
  }
}
```

https://replit.com/join/sucvdhpqoa-redneckz

Comment: thank you very much for this answer, is there any way that the method moveTo takes by as type int not double? Because, I have to use x and y for example in classes such as Canvas for codes such as fillOval or drawRect, where the parameters should be of type int.

Comment: You can cast `double` to `int` safely. And, of course, `double by` could be replaced with `int percent` and transformed to double internally `percent * 0.01`

Comment: Thank you, I have just learned how to convert double to int for drawing and changed everything to double, but I want to instead of print the points, make one point to move into others and then draw them. But somehow it doesn't work. I've posted below the codes.

Comment: do not forget to like my answers)

Comment: I tried but it says: Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.

Answer (score 0):

@AlexanderAlexandrov  I've change the type of my variables to double accordingly, now in one of my classes I have a method givePoints, which uses Scanner for asking a user  how many points he wants and what are the coordinates then it saves them  into an array of points with first element being always(0,0).
Another method takes an array of points as parameter and sort them in order of their distances to point(0,0).
These methods work perfectly. The problem is with method hitThepoints.
Here I want to first create the array of points, sort them, and then command my robot to hit all the points. robot is an object of class Robot extends circle, with position of type Point, that at first is at point(0,0)

```
public void hitThePoints(){

  Point[] poi=sortPoints (givePoints()); //Creates a sorted array of points
  Point short=new Point(poi[1].getX(),poi[1].getY());
  System.out.println(" the nearest point is :");
  System.out.println("("+short.getX()+ ","+short.getY()+")");
         
         for(int i=1; i<poi.length;i++){
              Point source=robot.position;
              Point target=new Point(poi[i].getX(), poi[i].getY());
                 while(source.getX()!=target.getX() && 
                       source.getY()!=target.getY()){
                  
                  robot.bewegeUm((source.moveTo(0.01,target)).getX(), 
                                (source.moveTo(0.01,target)).getY());

                  if(source.getX()!=target.getX() && 
                     source.getY()!=target.getY()){break;}

                  System.out.println(source.getX() +","+ source.getY());
                  
                  }
           }
      }
```